# How do I apply _.debounce to my discord bot?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, debouncing

I am having trouble adding debounce for this message. I want the bot to first send the message instantly like it does, but then pause for more than 7 secondss before sending again. I'm not sure how or where to apply debounce.

```
bot.on("typingStart", (channel , user) => {

    if (channel.id === Join2_channel) {
    channel.send('Type !join');
    
});
```

Comment: Just keep track of when you last sent the message (`new Date();`) and before sending another message, make sure it's been at least 7 seconds since then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Underscore's [`_.debounce`](https://underscorejs.org/#debounce):

> Creates and returns a new debounced version of the passed function which will postpone its execution until after wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time it was invoked. Useful for implementing behavior that should only happen after the input has stopped arriving. For example: rendering a preview of a Markdown comment, recalculating a layout after the window has stopped being resized, and so on.
>
> At the end of the wait interval, the function will be called with the arguments that were passed most recently to the debounced function.
>
> Pass true for the immediate argument to cause debounce to trigger the function on the leading instead of the trailing edge of the wait interval. Useful in circumstances like preventing accidental double-clicks on a "submit" button from firing a second time.

```
bot.on("typingStart", _.debounce((channel , user) => {
    
}, 7000, true));
```

You could directly copy the function as well.

```
// When a sequence of calls of the returned function ends, the argument
// function is triggered. The end of a sequence is defined by the `wait`
// parameter. If `immediate` is passed, the argument function will be
// triggered at the beginning of the sequence instead of at the end.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout, result;

  var later = function(context, args) {
    timeout = null;
    if (args) result = func.apply(context, args);
  };

  var debounced = restArguments(function(args) {
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    if (immediate) {
      var callNow = !timeout;
      timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
      if (callNow) result = func.apply(this, args);
    } else {
      timeout = delay(later, wait, this, args);
    }

    return result;
  });

  debounced.cancel = function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = null;
  };

  return debounced;
}
// Some functions take a variable number of arguments, or a few expected
// arguments at the beginning and then a variable number of values to operate
// on. This helper accumulates all remaining arguments past the function’s
// argument length (or an explicit `startIndex`), into an array that becomes
// the last argument. Similar to ES6’s "rest parameter".
function restArguments(func, startIndex) {
  startIndex = startIndex == null ? func.length - 1 : +startIndex;
  return function() {
    var length = Math.max(arguments.length - startIndex, 0),
        rest = Array(length),
        index = 0;
    for (; index < length; index++) {
      rest[index] = arguments[index + startIndex];
    }
    switch (startIndex) {
      case 0: return func.call(this, rest);
      case 1: return func.call(this, arguments[0], rest);
      case 2: return func.call(this, arguments[0], arguments[1], rest);
    }
    var args = Array(startIndex + 1);
    for (index = 0; index < startIndex; index++) {
      args[index] = arguments[index];
    }
    args[startIndex] = rest;
    return func.apply(this, args);
  };
}
bot.on("typingStart", debounce((channel, user) => {

}, 7000, true));
```

Comment: @joeydibbs Does the approach work for you?

Comment: When updating my code with this I get the error _ is not defined.



bot.on("typingStart", _.debounce( (channel , user) => {

    if (channel.id === Join2_channel) {
    channel.send('Type !join');
    
}, 7000, true));

Comment: @joeydibbs Are you using underscore.js? Your title seems to indicate it.

Comment: I am not. I'm a noob, sorry. Can I link to that library similar to jquery?

Comment: @joeydibbs Yes, you can add it like so: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.12.0/underscore-min.js"></script>`

Comment: SyntaxError: unexpected token < . That's how I remember doing it with html. I am writing a .js file and very new to this

Comment: @joeydibbs You needed to put that in your HTML file.

Comment: @joeydibbs Take a look at Package Installation on https://underscorejs.org/.

Comment: @joeydibbs I updated my answer with the entire code if you want to directly drop it into your file.

Comment: I am making a discord bot I don't have a html file. I, also, tried installing the package via node.js and still no luck.

Comment: @joeydibbs I updated my answer. Check the second part.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, however that didn't work as well. restArguments is not defined. I tried linking the underscore.js  with  var _ = require('underscore'); and get the TypeError : cannot read property of 'debounce' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous>